# Adding vars to a closure swift

Tags: swift

hey I'm a little confused about block syntax. I currently have a function defined like so:

```
func presentRateAlert(ID: Int, didDismiss: (() -> Void)?)
```

Currently I do not have any parameters in the block, but I would like to include two. `rating: Double?` and `message: String?`. How would I include these?

Comment: You say returning, but do you actually mean you want them to be the closure's *parameters* (i.e `presentRateAlert` will pass them in, and the caller will use them?)

Comment: @Hamish yes that's what I mean!

Comment: BTW, according to Swift naming conventions, variables, parameters, and function names should all start with lower-case letters. Thus your parameter `ID` should be `id` instead.

Answer (score 2):

In your function declaration, didDismiss is a closure. It's type is `(() -> Void)?)`, which is an Optional closure that takes no parameters, and returns `Void` (no result.)

If you change it to `(() -> (Double,String)?`

Then your closure returns a Tuple which contains a `Double` and a `String`.

(In Swift a function can only return one result. Normally you make that result a Tuple when you want to return more than one thing.)

### EDIT:

Based on your edits, it seems you want to add PARAMETERS to your closure, not a return value as you said originally.

An Optional closure that takes a Double and a String and does not return a value would be declared as `((Double, String) -> Void)?)`

A function that takes such a closure might look like this:

```
func test(id: Int, closure: ((Double, String) -> Void)?) {
    closure?(3.14, "pi")
}
```

And calling it might look like this:

```
test(id: 6, closure: {
    (aDouble, aString) in
    print("In closure, double = \(aDouble), string = \(aString)")
})
```

Comment: Sorry I got my words up in the question. I meant I want to pass parameters in the block. Not return values.

Comment: Oh, that's a horse (question) of a different color.

Comment: See the edit to my answer, based on your edited question.

Comment: Possibly worth mentioning that, curiously, we're allowed to include internal parameter names in the type annotation of the `closure` parameter of `test` (namely, `func test(id: Int, closure: ((_ rating: Double, _ message: String) -> Void)?) { ... }`); external parameter names that, afaict, cannot be "accessed" (I would've hoped for `$0.message` and `$0.rating` in a closure supplied to the function, but no ...), but could hold semantic value by their inclusion into the signature of the `test` function :)

Comment: ... I had to dig further into the curiosity of my last comment, and ended up [asking a question regarding it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42637340/why-may-we-use-internal-argument-labels-in-type-annotations-of-closures-when). Tbh, the "functionality" covered by my last comment seems kind of weird.