# Why may we use "internal argument labels" in type annotations of closures, when they (seemingly) can never be accessed?

Tags: swift, closures

#### Background

This is naturally legal:

```
let closure: (Int, Int) -> () = { print($0 + $1) }
closure(1, 2) // 3
```

Whereas, since the implementation of evolution proposal

- [SE-0111: Remove type system significance of function argument labels](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0111-remove-arg-label-type-significance.md)

in Swift 3, the following is not legal:

```
let closure: (a: Int, b: Int) -> () = { /* ... */ }
```

> Error: function types may not have argument label `a`, use `_` instead.

Which is expected, as, quoting from SE-0111:

> *Function types may only be defined in terms of the types of the formal
>   parameters and the return value.*

Curiously, however (and as prompted by the error message above), this is legal:

```
let closure: (_ a: Int, _ b: Int) -> () = { print($0 + $1) }
closure(1, 2) // 3
```

However, as far as I can tell, we can't ever make use of `a` and `b` above (they shouldn't even be allowed, as they are not part of the types of the parameters?).

#### Question

- Is there any reason for the final code snippet above to be legal? Can we make use or access the "internal argument labels" `a` and `b` (given the quote, we shouldn't ...), or is this possibly an oversight in the implementation of SE-0111?

Comment: Take a look at the [rationale](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution-announce/2016-July/000216.html) and [additional commentary](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution-announce/2016-July/000233.html) for the proposal :) The Swift team are aware of the uselessness of "cosmetic" parameter labels, and there's a sketch of how they believe they should be implemented in the future (being a part of the decleration name, rather than type).

Comment: @Hamish aha, so they do have an intended semant-, erm sorry, cosmetic value! :) a quote from, say, the additional commentary fully answers this question, if you feel like posting an answer (I'm off to sleep this very instant though, so I'll accept it in the morning). Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're observing is the ability to define "purely cosmetic" parameter labels for closure types. This was accepted as a part of [SE-0111](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0111-remove-arg-label-type-significance.md), as stated [in the rationale](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution-announce/2016-July/000216.html):

> In response to community feedback, the core team is accepting the proposal with a revision to allow “purely cosmetic” parameter labels in closure types for documentation (as outlined in [the alternatives section](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0111-remove-arg-label-type-significance.md#allow-spelling-function-types-with-purely-cosmetic-argument-labels)).

The syntax for these cosmetic parameter labels changed after the proposal to require an argument label of `_`, in order to make it explicit that the cosmetic labels aren't used at the call-site. This was detailed in [an additional commentary](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution-announce/2016-July/000233.html):

> The specific revision requested by the core team to SE-0111 is that
>   all “cosmetic” labels should be required to include an API name of `_`. 
>   For example, this would not be allowed:
>
> ```
> var op : (lhs : Int, rhs : Int) -> Int
> ```
>
> instead, it should be spelled as:
>
> ```
> var op : (_ lhs : Int, _ rhs : Int) -> Int
> ```

Although really, in practice, this makes the cosmetic labels fairly useless, as they don't show up at the call-site or even in auto-completion – only at the actual declaration itself. Therefore their intent to be self-documenting is somewhat lost.

The Swift team are aware of this shortcoming, and will be looking to make a purely additive change post-Swift 3 in order to rectify the situation.

Here's the sketch that they proposed (again, in [the additional commentary](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution-announce/2016-July/000233.html)):

> First, we extend declaration names for variables, properties, and parameters to allow *parameter names* as part of their declaration name.  For example:
>
> ```
> var op(lhs:,rhs:) : (Int, Int) -> Int    // variable or property.
> x = op(lhs: 1, rhs: 2)       // use of the variable or property.
>
> // API name of parameter is “opToUse”, internal name is "op(lhs:,rhs:)”.
> func foo(opToUse  op(lhs:,rhs:) : (Int, Int) -> Int) {
>   x = op(lhs: 1, rhs: 2)     // use of the parameter
> }
> foo(opToUse: +)             // call of the function
> ```
>
> This will restore the ability to express the idea of a closure
>   parameter that carries labels as part of its declaration, without
>   requiring parameter labels to be part of the type system (allowing,
>   e.g. the operator + to be passed into something that requires
>   parameter labels).
>
> Second, extend the rules for function types to allow parameter API
>   labels *if and only if* they are used as the type of a declaration
>   that allows parameter labels, and interpret them as a sugar form for
>   providing those labels on the underlying declaration.  This means that
>   the example above could be spelled as:
>
> ```
> var op : (lhs: Int, rhs: Int) -> Int    // Nice declaration syntax
> x = op(lhs: 1, rhs: 2)                  // Same as above
>
> // API name of parameter is “opToUse”, internal name is "op(lhs:,rhs:)”.
> func foo(opToUse op : (lhs: Int, rhs: Int) -> Int) {
>   x = op(lhs: 1, rhs: 2)     // Same as above.
> }
> foo(opToUse: +)              // Same as above.
> ```

This proposed solution quite nicely allows the labels to be used at the call-site, allowing for self-documenting parameter labels, while not complicating the type-system with them. Additionally (in most cases) it allows for the expressive syntax of writing the labels next to the parameter types of the closure – which we were used to doing pre-Swift 3.

Comment: Great post, yet again, Hamish. Looking forward to this tweak being implemented.

Comment: Thanks! The sketch in the final quote above looks really useful, I hope it'll become a reality before too long.

Comment: Really close to the gold badge now btw, I put my money on one coming in tomorrow! :)

Comment: @dfri \*stretches fingers\* Let's try for today :D (although really it's impossible to predict how many "answerable" questions will be asked which I can answer)

Answer (score 4):

There have been complaints, not unreasonable, that if you remove the ability to name the parameters, you lose an important aspect of the human communication that tells a future maintainer or user of this code the *purpose* of these parameters. Well, that ability *has* been removed as far as *external* parameter names are concerned. But by leaving it open to sneak past the compiler by using just *internal* parameter names, we recover at least something of that communication.

However, we do not recover *enough* of that communication, because the internal parameters don't show up in code completion:

[image]

This has been criticized as a flaw in the new regime on this matter, and, in my opinion, rightly so.

Comment: And for this very reason the story is probably not yet over, as Hamish explains.

Comment: Thanks matt, I also agree that this is currently somewhat flawed. Hopefully the proposed changes quotes i Hamish:s answer will come into life sooner rather than later.