# Returned function doesn't behave as global one

Tags: swift

I don't understand this behavior in Swift (3.1)

```
// Code segment 1
func foo(bar baz: Int) -> Void {
    print(baz)
}
foo(bar: 42) // => prints 42

// Code segment 2
func gimmeFunc() -> (Int) -> Void {
    func foo(bar baz: Int) -> Void {
        print(baz)
    }
    return foo
}

var qux = gimmeFunc()
qux(bar: 42) // I get ".. error: extraneous argument label 'bar:' in call"

qux(42) // Works
```

Why does the returned function from Code segment 2 behave differently?

Comment: The following should be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42637340/why-may-we-use-internal-argument-labels-in-type-annotations-of-closures-when

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why may we use "internal argument labels" in type annotations of closures, when they (seemingly) can never be accessed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42637340/why-may-we-use-internal-argument-labels-in-type-annotations-of-closures-when)